# ExtJS /Java/Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, extjs, extjs4

I have to build small app using Eclipse JEE framework and ExtJS for the frontend part. I downloaded Eclipse Kepler for JEE developers. All went good until I imported extjs into my project. Eclipse started to use CPU by 100% which gets the computer stuck. What eclipse is doing is building workspace and it needs 100% of CPU and lot of time to process 14000 files in ExtJS framework.

Ok I turned off all validators but still the PC is stuck only on javaw.exe process. 
I also turned of "Build automatically" option. Still 100% CPU

I tried to add only necessary files from ExtJS but the GUI I am getting is ruined, so that means only ext-all-debug.js file and ext-all.css is not enough to create your application.

What do I do? Or should I state this question like this:

Which files/libraries form the extjs-gpl.zip should I add to my project so that I see all GUI parts rendered properly?

I am using remote computer which has 1.5 GB RAM so I cannot change it. Eclipse JEE version eats up to 600 - 700 MB

Comment: Will Aptana behave more reliably? Or Netbeans? hehehe

Comment: Why are you loading ExtJs into JEE Eclipse ? Maybe JEE Eclipse isn't parsing the files correctly ? I use ExtJs in Eclipse without problem.

Comment: I just copied the extjs folder in webapp folder of my maven-webapp application. It gets stuck, CPU 100%. I am not sure what it is doing.

Comment: I used to be an Eclipse user, had to abandon it for this very same reason when I started getting into ExtJS. IntelliJ actually understands and integrates ExtJS very well and also Netbeans does not have major problems with it. I believe that Sencha's answer to this issue was to come out with the Sencha Eclipse Plugin but you have to pay up for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript build process scans all files, folders, projects and libraries that are on the project's JavaScript Build Path. 
It seems like Eclipse consumes a lot of CPU and RAM when trying to perform the build process.

I had the same issue and I couldn't found which files form extjs should be added to my projects. So, I excluded my extjs files from javascript build path and It is worked fine. 
Try to do this by going to the project *properties -- JavaScript -- Include Path -- Source tab*, then click on the excluded icon and add extjs folder. [Source](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/setting_the_javascript_build_path.htm#Source)

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the same problem. Although the question was asked some time ago I'd like to add another solution which I prefere especially if I have several projects using ExtJS.

You can add the ExtJS-Files as a static, external Web Module to your web server.
Therefore doubleclick the server in server view. Select the tab 'Modules' at the bottom. Add an external web module. Document base represents the path on your file system. Path represents the path on the web server to use in your html files. You can take this path for linking ExtJS in all your projects without configuring each project itself.